# Nested json files - Python

Tags: python, json, pandas

Good afternoon all,

I've been reading through the various posts regarding reading .json files using pandas but so far I've not been sucessful extract.

I need to read a specific 'score' in the json file of which I'll then iterate through all the json files I have as the label would be the same.

In the below how would I read the 'score'? I've tried using the normalise function but regardless of the agruement I put in I cannot get any closer.

Part of the json file:

```
 "template_id": "template_fe61177cb0eb4642901b1eae9488fbb4",
 "audit_id": "audit_1a0e9ef4a7914286808accb3dcb0700b",
 "archived": false,
 "created_at": "2022-10-07T08:00:14.021Z",
 "modified_at": "2022-10-07T08:05:56.594Z",
 "audit_data": {
  "score": 10,
  "total_score": 11,
  "score_percentage": 90.909,
  "name": "7 Oct 2022 / Test",
  "duration": 240,
  "authorship": {
   "device_id": "user_65c3799b0f1a48549cacbceca244e1db",
   "owner": "test",
   "owner_id": "user_65c3799b0f1a48549cacbceca244e1db",
   "author": "test",
   "author_id": "user_65c3799b0f1a48549cacbceca244e1db"
  },
  "date_completed": "2022-10-07T08:05:55.860Z",
  "date_modified": "2022-10-07T08:05:56.594Z",
  "date_started": "2022-10-07T08:00:13.000Z",
  "site": {
   "name": "Blue Warehouse"
  }
 },
 "template_data": {
  "authorship": {
   "device_id": "user_4bb896b5308341f7a7543a32f6c1f3ec",
   "owner": "test",
   "owner_id": "user_4bb896b5308341f7a7543a32f6c1f3ec",
   "author": "test",
   "author_id": "user_4bb896b5308341f7a7543a32f6c1f3ec"
  },
  "metadata": {
   "description": "",
   "name": "RCS",
   "image": {
    "date_created": "2022-04-12T13:27:18.852Z",
    "file_ext": "png",
    "label": "Go \u0026 See icon.PNG",
    "media_id": "cf944a4b-7589-47e6-b42a-8d17f06b7031",
    "href": "https://1"
   }
  },
  "response_sets": {
   "5b69aee5-0532-46a4-b2f5-d020d4d5381d": {
    "id": "5b69aee5-0532-46a4-b2f5-d020d4d5381d",
    "type": "question",
    "responses": [
     {
      "id": "ef4abf51-3361-46f5-ba04-70c23c85ca20",
      "label": "Good",
      "colour": "19,133,95",
      ***"score": 1,***
      "enable_score": true
     },
```

Thanks for your help.

Rob.

Comment: The format of the example json you gave is not correct. Please check and rewrite correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This is done without `pandas`

```py
import json

with open("my_file.json", 'r') as f:
    my_dict = json.load(f)

score = my_dict["response_sets"]["5b69aee5-0532-46a4-b2f5-d020d4d5381d"]["responses"][0]["score"]
```